# Selecting DISTINCT where not null in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, distinct

I've got a table that has, for example, `ID` and `Name`.

There are multiple rows that contain blank names, but there also can be multiple rows with the same name. I'd like to select all `ID`s, counting each name only once (`DISTINCT`), but selecting ALL of the blanks.

The following query naturally only selects ONE blank name. **How can I select all the distinct names plus all of the blank names?**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID
FROM TestTable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID FROM TestTable where Name <> ''
union all
SELECT Name, ID FROM TestTable where Name = ''
```

Comment: Can you explain the `<>`? I can figure it out, but would like to see a written explanation =)

Comment: @John `not equal to`, same as `!=` in many programming languages

Answer (score 1):

Only slight improvement I can think of would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, ID FROM TestTable where Name <> ''
union all
SELECT '', ID FROM TestTable where Name IS NULL OR Name = ''
```